# how can I split and convert string to integer?

Tags: c

```
string input = 1999-12-05
int year=1999
int month=12
int day=05
```

I want to split input to new three variable.Thank you.

Comment: Use `sscanf()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sscanf`:

```c
char* input = "1999-12-05";
int year;
int month;
int day;
sscanf(input, "%d-%d-%d", &year, &month, &day);
printf("year: %d, month: %d, day: %d\n", year, month, day);
```

**[demo](https://onlinegdb.com/7UqSbI3qo)**

Comment: It's best to check `sscanf`'s return value.  If it's not 3 in this case, something has gone wrong, and not all three values were converted.